# Observing a function in Angular 5

Tags: angular, observable, subscriber

**I think I don't understand Observables**. I've got 2 components **ChartsComponent** and let's say **AppComponent**. AppComponent fetches info from database and passes it through **ChartsService** to ChartsComponent to paint it. Thing is ChartsComponent's selector **`<charts></charts>`** is loaded inside AppComponent at the same time, therefore the database data arrives to ChartsComponent **after construction**. I thought I could use an Observable to monitor the Database response and update a ngIf boolean variable to load the selector and build ChartsComponent.

App.component.html:

```
<div *ngIf="chartsBoolean">
    <charts-component-selector></charts-component-selector>
</div>
```

App.component.ts. Would I start the Observable in the constructor?

```
constructor( private chartsService: ChartsService ){

    var chartsBoolean = false;

    var myObservable = new Observable(observer =>{
        this.chartsBoolean = true;
    })

    let subscription = myObservable.subscribe(

    );
}

//this is the method I think I should be monitoring

getChartDataFromDatabase(){
    //onSuccess inserts database response into charData 
    this.chartsService.setChartData(charData);
}
```

Charts.service.ts => just Getters and Setters

Charts.Component.ts

```
constructor( private chartsService: ChartsService ){

    this.chartsService.getChartData();

    );
}
```

As you can see I'm just stuck when planning the boundaries of the Observable and the subscriber. I know it's basic stuff but it's just not kicking in. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think observables should subscribe on ngOnInit and unsubscribe on ngOnDestroy

Comment: I would strongly recommend you to take a look at https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#observable-data

Answer (score 0):

So I worked out an answer but forgot to post it.

app.component.html

```
...
<div *ngIf="chartsBoolean">
    <charts-component-selector></charts-component-selector>
</div>
...
```

app.service.ts

```
    query(): Observable<HttpResponse<any[]>> {
            return this.http.get<any[]>(this.resourceUrl, { params: options, observe: 'response' })
                .map((res: HttpResponse<any[]>) => this.convertArrayResponse(res));
    }
```

app.component.ts

```
    loadCharts(){
            this.chartsBoolean = false;
            this.AppService.query().subscribe(
                (res: HttpResponse < string[] > ) => this.onSuccess(res.body),
                (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message)
            );
    }

    private onSuccess(data){
        this.chartsService.setChartData(data);
        this.chartsBoolean = true;
    }
```

By changing chartsBoolean to "true" after setting the values you need in ChartsService, tha values are available on construction for the ChartsComponent. OnSuccess can take it's time to get triggered with data from Database, and ChartsComponent is never built before it has access to that data.